# Typescript error: Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'Object[]' and 'number'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I am unsure what is happening or how to resolve this type error. I get this warning for the console.log statement. I need to do more logic but I am not sure why I get this when I am clearly comparing the length of an array "OeeDataType[]" to a number. Both are numbers. Please help.
The error occurs in the values.length > 0

```
  useEffect(() => {
    groupHistoricalData.forEach((values) => {
      console.log(values.length > 0);
    });
  }, [groupHistoricalData]);
```

types...

```
interface OEECardProps {
  machinesByGroup: MachinesByGroup[];
  groupHistoricalData: HistoricalTsiDataType[];
}
export interface HistoricalTsiDataType {
  [key: string]: OeeDataType[];
}
export interface OeeDataType {
  timestamp: number;
  oee: number | null;
}
export interface MachinesByGroup {
  machineSerial: string;
  machineName: string;
}
```

If you want a data example, please let me know and I can post that. I am eventually trying to loop through the OeeDataType[] to grab the .oee but it will not let me. Strangely, the code runs successfully even though these errors exist in the console.
[image]

Comment: What is `groupHistoricalData` and what is it's type?

Comment: It is defined in the second code block above

Comment: Why is this getting dislikes? I have all reproduceable code and if you need anything, just ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `values` element of `groupHistoricalData` is a `HistoricalTsiDataType`, which is a `{ [key: string]: OeeDataType[] }` (or, if you prefer, a `Record<string, OeeDataType[]>`).

Therefore, `values.length` is an `OeeDataType[]` - same as `values.foo` or `values[myLoopVariable]` or whatever.

You may want an extra nested loop:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    groupHistoricalData.forEach((data) => {
      Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, values]) => {
        console.log(values.length > 0);
      });
    });
  }, [groupHistoricalData]);
```

Comment: This does work, and it is what I initially tried but when I try to get the .oee typescript complains about it. "Property 'oee' does not exist on type 'OeeDataType[]'". This happens when I try console.log(values.oee)

Comment: @JustinO - Then you probably need another nested loop. See my update.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. If you go back to the original one you posted and change the console.log to this "console.log(values)", the logged result is either [] or {date: '2022-11-09', oee: 1}. This might be the issue.

Comment: @JustinO, it works when I test it. I think it's very likely that your code has gotten confused from trying to track multiple nested loops, but I'm not sure how to further help. (It's also possible that the `groupHistoricalData` prop is getting passed in incorrectly.)

Comment: Thanks. I will do some investigating. My comment above was wrong. It always produces {date: '2022-11-09', oee: 1} and thus, I do not know why I cannot get the oee key here. Can you revert to the previous answer you had and I can accept that for now. I need to make a new issue for this one I think.